# MYSQL INTERGRATION TO MICROSOFT SQL DATABASE

Tags: mysql

I just need some quick advice on how does one go about integrating mysql into a Microsoft sql database

Comment: Your question is too broad to get a "quick advice".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate data from mysql to microsoft sql, use a data integration tool. [Talend Open Studio for data integration](https://www.talend.com/download/) is one of such tools.